# how to print keys and values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is what I have

```
prices={'banana':4,'apple':2,'orange':1.5,'pear':3}
stock={'banana':6,'apple':0,'orange':32,'pear':15}
```

I want to print it in following format:

```
item
price: x
stock: x
```

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: apple
price: 2
stock: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
prices = {'banana': 4, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 1.5, 'pear': 3}
stock = {'banana': 6, 'apple': 0, 'orange': 32, 'pear': 15}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    try:
        print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
    except KeyError:
        print "stock: KeyError"
```

Which would yield:

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
```

---

However I think a nested dictionary would be more appropriate here:

```
items = {'banana': {'price': 4,   'stock': 6 },
         'apple':  {'price': 2,   'stock': 0 },
         'orange': {'price': 1.5, 'stock': 32},
         'pear':   {'price': 3,   'stock': 15},
        }

for key in items:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % items[key]['price']
    print "stock: %s" % items[key]['stock']
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over a dictionary: yields keys. Use the key to access value of the dictionary values.

```
prices={'banana':4,'apple':2,'orange':1.5,'pear':3}
stock={'banana':6,'apple':0,'orange':32,'pear':15}
for fruit in prices:
    print(fruit)
    print('price: {}'.format(prices[fruit]))
    print('stock: {}'.format(stock[fruit]))
```

output:

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
```

Comment: Sorry .Let me ask you as I am just a beginner. Is this a code in python?

Comment: @FrancisS, Yes it is. It runs on both in Python 2.x, Python 3.x.

Comment: You tagged the question as Python, so the code in the answer is Python. That's pretty simple code. Why do you think it could be another programming language?

Comment: Im so sorry. I could see too  many brackets in here. So I got confused like is this really python cos I havent come across so much of brackets and those .formats and all.really sorry :P

Comment: If you're going to use the key to lookup the value, you may as well iterate over items in the first place

Answer (score 1):

```
prices={'banana':4,'apple':2,'orange':1.5,'pear':3}
stock={'banana':6,'apple':0,'orange':32,'pear':15}

for item in prices:
    print item
    print "price: ",prices[item]
    print "stock: ",stock[item]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over a keys from one dictionary...

```
  for key in prices:
      print key
      print "price: %d" % prices[key]
      print "stock: %d" % stock[key]
```